# Datagridview, how to get min, max, and average on certain range

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which contains 1000 data points. I have successfully calculated the min, max, and average of the values in my DataGridView, but now I want to get the min, max, and average values only from a certain range. For example, data in 101 to 200 or 201 to 300 .

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dataGridView1.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1

    sum_tmp = sum_tmp + dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value

    If i = 0 Then
        max_tmp = dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        min_tmp = dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
    End If

    If max_tmp < dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value Then
        max_tmp = dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
    End If

    If min_tmp > dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value Then
        min_tmp = dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
    End If

Next

avg_tmp = sum_tmp / dataGridView1.Rows.Count()
```

Above is my code to get the value. I have tried using integer variable that changed by selecting combobox but still always get 0 value on min. Sadly it shows the right value on the average. How is it possibly wrong?

Comment: can you use the `Filter function` and use the `Between method` to get the values using `DataView` ? do a google search on DataTable.FIlter() Method`

Comment: when do you want to calculate the sum or average? Does the user select some rows and clicks on a context menu item?

Comment: @AlexB. you raise a good question. I edited my answer to simplify how the function is called, with two single values to input (first row, last row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a LINQ expression to get an enumerable collection of the values you want to process, then use built-in functions to get the max, min, and average

Define a struct which will hold the resulting calculations

```
Private Structure ResultsStruct
    Public Min As Single
    Public Max As Single
    Public Average As Single
    Public Sum As Single
End Structure
```

This function returns the struct when called. Pass in the first row index and last row index.

```
Private Function getResults(firstRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer) As ResultsStruct
    Dim skipRows = firstRow - 1
    Dim takeRows = lastRow - skipRows
    Dim values = DataGridView1.Rows.
        OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)().
        Select(Of Single)(Function(r) Single.Parse(r.Cells(0).Value.ToString())).
        Skip(skipRows).
        Take(takeRows)
    Dim max = values.Max()
    Dim min = values.Min()
    Dim avg = values.Average()
    Dim result As New ResultsStruct() With {.Max = values.Max(),
                                            .Min = values.Min(),
                                            .Average = values.Average(),
                                            .Sum = values.Sum()}
    Return result
End Function
```

How it's called

```
Dim result = getResults(firstRow:=201, lastRow:=300)
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Max: {0}, Min: {1}, Avg: {2}, Sum: {3}",
                              result.Max, result.Min, result.Average, result.Sum))
```

Replace `201` and `300` in the example with the range you are interested in, whether it is from the user selecting the grid or some other means of input.

Comment: thank you for the answer, now it solve my "low of basic knowledge" :D